# How can I store all data the user inputs and then show them if they want to see all of them

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and have been making a program that will ask user to enter two numbers and the operation they want. It will show the result and ask if they want to try again. And now if they tried them 5 times or 3 times something will display asking if they want to see their input history. I have been making this 3 days now but I am stuck thinking on how to do it correctly. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void add(int a, int b, int c);
void subtract(int a, int b, int c);
void multiply(int a, int b, int c);
void divide(double a, double b, double c);
void remainder(int a, int b, int c);
int main(){
    Start:
    int num[10],c,r=2,i=1;
    char x,y,z; 

        cout<<"Enter Two Integers:\n";
            for(i;i<=r;i++){

                cin>>num[i];
            }
    Operation:
        cout<<"Choose Operation: \n"
            <<"   A --- Addition  \n"
            <<"   S --- Subtraction   \n"
            <<"   M --- Multiplication   \n"
            <<"   D --- Division   \n"
            <<"   R --- Remainder   \n";
        cout<<"Operation: ";
        cin>>z;
        if(z=='a'||z=='A'){
            add(num[1],num[2],c);
        }
        else if(z=='s'||z=='S'){
            subtract(num[1],num[2],c);
        }
        else if(z=='m'||z=='M'){
            multiply(num[1],num[2],c);
        }
        else if(z=='d'||z=='D'){
            divide(num[1],num[2],c);
        }
        else if(z=='r'||z=='R'){
            remainder(num[1],num[2],c);
        }else{
            system("CLS");
            cout<<"Please choose the right option below.\n\n";
            goto Operation; 
        }
        cout<<"\nDo you want to try again? (Y or N): ";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"\n";
        if(x=='Y'||x=='y'){
            system("CLS");
            goto Start;
            i=3;
            r=4;
        }else{
            cout<<"Do you to see input history? (Y or N): ";
            cin>>x;
            if(x=='Y'||x=='y'){
                system("CLS");
                cout<<"Input history: \n";
                if(z=='a'||z=='A'){
                    c=num[1]+num[2];
                    cout<<num[1]<<" + "<<num[2]<<" = "<<c<<endl;
                }
                else if(z=='s'||z=='S'){
                    c=num[1]-num[2];
                    cout<<num[1]<<" - "<<num[2]<<" = "<<c<<endl;
                }
                else if(z=='m'||z=='M'){
                    c=num[1]+num[2];
                    cout<<num[1]<<" * "<<num[2]<<" = "<<c<<endl;
                }
                else if(z=='d'||z=='D'){
                    c=num[1]/num[2];
                    cout<<num[1]<<" / "<<num[2]<<" = "<<c<<endl;
                }
                else if(z=='r'||z=='R'){
                    c=num[1]%num[2];
                    cout<<num[1]<<" % "<<num[2]<<" = "<<c<<endl;
                }       
            }
            else{
                system("CLS");
                cout<<"Thanks for using our program!\n";
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
void add(int a, int b, int c){
    c=a+b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<c<<endl;
    }
void subtract(int a, int b, int c){
    c=a-b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<c<<endl;
}
void multiply(int a, int b, int c){
    c=a/b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<c<<endl;
    }
void divide(double a, double b, double c){
    c=a/b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<c<<endl;
}
void remainder(int a, int b, int c){
    c=a%b;
    cout<<"The answer is: "<<c<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Could you give sample input and outputs? what is wrong and what you expect?

Comment: Beside your actual question you should consider not to use labels and a loop instead.
E.g `do { // ... ; cin >> x; } while( x == 'y' || x == 'Y');`

Comment: One thing I'm very curious about is where beginners learn about `goto`. No decent book mentions it - at least not in the introductory part - and it's not in any beginners' tutorial that I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

> *How can I store all data the user inputs and then show them if they want to see all of them ?*

I think you may want to create a structure that represents an operation.

For example:

```
struct Operation
{
    double left_operand_;
    double right_operand_;
    char operator_;
    double result_;
};
```

And then, in your code, you could add a `std::vector<Operation>` (for storing the history) that is supposed to be populated every time the user ask for an operation.

When the user asks for history, you just have to iterate over the vector and show each stored `Operation`.

---

As you mentioned you are quite new in C++, you may be interested to read this [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you don't already know what is `std::vector` nor how to use it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but our Professor told us to only use arrays and fucntions so we cant use vectors.

Comment: Then just use an array of this structure for your history: `struct Operation history[5]`

Comment: @newbie Then you should have mentioned it in your question. You can always dynamically allocate a raw array in memory manually instead, if you don't want to use `std::vector`.